# How to create Enrollment Discovery.svc web service for Windows Phone Management

Tags: windows-phone-8

How would I create a enrollment Discovery webservice for windows phone? Something which can respond to `/EnrollmentServer/Discovery.svc` GET request.
Could not find anything on Windows Phone Dev Forum?

> Note: I am a Java Developer and completely new to Visual Studio and C#